# SSIS Realtime scenarios-Send Mail Task

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

how to get email from send mail task when Excel sheet have records daily

Example: I have 10 records in excel sheet on Monday

```
       12 records on Tuesday

       7 records on Wednesday

       no records on Thursday on so on.
```

Scenario: If records are there i get mail. if no records are there i didn't get mail daily

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:

- Set up a User variable with the scope of the whole package
- Use a row count transformation between the source and destination and stored it in the user variable
- In control flow added constraints between data flow task and send mail task so that one or another 'path' was taken dependant on row count